# How can I clone and remove a html form with JavaScript(js)?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, removechild

I want to clone a form and then have the option to remove the form that I have just created. I know how to clone it, but not how to remove it. I have only be able to remove the original form, but not the clonned form.

This is my code:

```js
function duplicate(id) {
  var elmnt = document.getElementById(id);
  var cln = elmnt.cloneNode(true);
  var num = 1;
  cln.id = id + num;
  document.body.appendChild(cln);
}

function remove(id) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(id);
  elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}
```

```html
<form class="f0" action="action.php" id="f0">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="">
  <button onclick="duplicate('f0')">Duplicate</button>
  <button onclick="remove('f0')">Remove</button>
  <input type="submit" value="Next"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `id`s for this at all.

The minimal change is to pass `this` into `remove` from the `onclick` (and, since you don't want it to submit the form, give it a `type`):

```
<button onclick="remove(this)" type="button">Next</button>
```

Then, in `remove`, use the button element that's passed in to find the form it's in:

```
function remove(button) {
    var form = button.closest("form");
    form.parentNode.removeChild(form);
}
```

You can make a similar change to `duplicate`:

```
function duplicate(button) {
    var form = button.closest("form").cloneNode(true);
    document.body.appendChild(form);
}
```

Be sure to remove the `id` from the form, since it's not needed and would be duplicated by the above.

Live Example:

```js
function remove(button) {
    var form = button.closest("form");
    form.parentNode.removeChild(form);
}

function duplicate(button) {
    var form = button.closest("form").cloneNode(true);
    document.body.appendChild(form);
}
```

```html
<form class="f0" action="action.php">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="">
  <button onclick="duplicate(this)" type="button">Duplicate</button>
  <button onclick="remove(this)" type="button">Next</button>
</form>
```

---

But even better would be to not use the `onclick` attribute at all, because when you do you have to use global functions, and globals are best avoided. Use modern event handling (`addEventListener`) instead:

```js
function remove() {
    var form = this.closest("form");
    form.parentNode.removeChild(form);
}

function duplicate() {
    var form = this.closest("form").cloneNode(true);
    setupHandlers(form);
    document.body.appendChild(form);
}

function setupHandlers(form) {
    form.querySelector(".form-duplicate").addEventListener("click", duplicate);
    form.querySelector(".form-remove").addEventListener("click", remove);
}

// Setup handlers on any initially-present forms
document.querySelectorAll(".f0").forEach(setupHandlers);
```

```html
<form class="f0" action="action.php">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="">
  <button class="form-duplicate" type="button">Duplicate</button>
  <button class="form-remove" type="button">Next</button>
</form>
```

Another option is to use event delegation, handling the clicks on the container element all of these forms are in (`body` in your example):

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var btn = e.target.closest(".form-duplicate");
    if (btn && this.contains(btn)) {
        duplicate(btn);
        return;
    }
    btn = e.target.closest(".form-remove");
    if (btn && this.contains(btn)) {
        remove(btn);
        return;
    }
});

function remove(btn) {
    var form = btn.closest("form");
    form.parentNode.removeChild(form);
}

function duplicate(btn) {
    var form = btn.closest("form").cloneNode(true);
    document.body.appendChild(form);
}
```

```html
<form class="f0" action="action.php">
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="">
  <button class="form-duplicate" type="button">Duplicate</button>
  <button class="form-remove" type="button">Next</button>
</form>
```

Note that [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) is relatively new, you'll need a polyfill for IE.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. How could I hide the remove button on the first form?

Comment: @AndoniDíezGuerra - Give it `style="display: none"` and when cloning it, find it in the form and do `.style.display = ""` on it to make it use its default display setting.

Comment: I understand the first part, but not the second part. When I duplicate the form, all the forms will have the two buttons, except the first form. So, how do I find the last form created to display the remove button?

Comment: @AndoniDíezGuerra - The code examples in the answer show doing that. If the starting point is a button in the form, you get the form via `var form = btn.closest("form");` To find a button in the form (with the classes I've added), `var btn = form.closest(".form-remove");`.

Comment: I´m doing that, but it says that btn is a null value

Comment: @AndoniDíezGuerra - In `duplicate`, after you've cloned the form: `form.querySelector(".form-remove").style.display = "";` (again, once you've added the classes I've added).

Comment: Thanks for all, this time worked. I think it was for the querySelector method, because the other times I didn´t use it

Comment: Now, I want to get a variable number of clones. That number will be specified by the user. How could I do it?